# What happens when a member of the main house of the Hyuuga clan marries a member of the branch house of the Hyuuga clan?

Tags: naruto

I've been thinking about it for a while now, but what if a member of the main house of the Hyuuga clan marries a member of the branch house of the Hyuuga clan ?

I've searched everywhere for the answer, but I couldn't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: I don't think that ever happened due to the strict rules of the familly that sees the branch members as a protection force for the main members.

Comment: I think the branch one would be treated as a main family from that time on, but only him/her and not his/her parents and siblings.

Answer (score 1):

**At the end of the day, both are still "Hyuuga".**

We remember from all the way back to Hinata vs Neji that his father cries and says "I wish I bore you into the main family". Then, even if his father was a branch member, had his wife been a main member, Neji would be a main member as well.

Other than that, their problems were settled after Naruto puts Neji's mind back in his head after they fought in the Chuunin exam. In the flashback as well, Neji's father asks Hinata's father to tell Neji the full story when he gets older but at first, he refuses.

Hinata's father apologizes to Neji after his fight against Naruto and it is implied that there is some harmony between the 2 families. After that it seems that the tension between the families calms down.

Comment: Please add references to your answer (manga chapter or anime episode for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Until more is revealed, I would speculate that the two houses do not typically marry each other. But let's say that a marriage does happen, do they both get put in the same house? What about their children? Would the clan even allow marriages like that to happen?

If such a marriage is looked down upon by the clan, maybe it could mean the two are forced into the branch house or are ostracised from the clan completely. Maybe their children are placed into the branch house.

Maybe gender plays a role. It could be that the couple takes the house of the husband or wife. Ultimately, we don't know enough of the Hyuuga clan's marriage customs to give you a real answer.

In fact, there's not much info on what puts someone into the main house or branch house. Neji's father is put into the branch house although Neji's uncle is placed into the main house.

It's an interesting scenario for sure.

Answer (score 0):

That would probably be the most normal thing to happen : Neji explains in episodes 60-62 that everyone is considered side branch except the first child of the main branch, and that there is only one Main Branch.

Then, the only people the Main Branch could marry would be Side Branch people or people outside the clan, and it seems like they would usually marry inside the clan to ensure the Byakugan is passed down to the next Main Branch heir (however this may not be the case).

Therefore, I would assume that when a main Branch marries a side branch the one who was side branch would probably gain some stature but the one who was always main branch would still be the leader of the clan.

> Sources :
>
> - [Hyuga Clan Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hy%C5%ABga_Clan).
> - Naruto episode 60-62.